# SQL Days since last unavailable

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table (redshift db) with the following sample:

```
product_id | date    | is_unavailable 
1          | 1st Jan | 1              
1          | 2nd Jan | 0              
1          | 3rd Jan | 0              
1          | 4rd Jan | 1
```

Here , a combination of `date` and `product_id` is `unique`. I need to have a 4th column: "Days since last unavailable".

Here is the output required:

```
product_id | date    | is_unavailable | days_since_last_unavailable
    1      | 1st Jan | 1              |          -            
    1      | 2nd Jan | 0              |          1          
    1      | 3rd Jan | 0              |          2           
    1      | 4rd Jan | 1              |          0
```

I thought of using `lag` window function with `partition over product_id` , however, an additional condition of `unavailable_flag` has to be checked here which I cannot accommodate in my query.

select *, 
    date-lag(date) over (partition by product_id order by date)
    as days_since_last_unavailbale
from mytable
order by product_id

However, I can't figure out how to use unavailable_flag since it is required to find the last date with unavailable_flag=1

Comment: Unclear.  Please tag with the database you are using, include your query, along with sample input/output data.

Comment: Could you show the query you got so far?
Please show example data of your table and your expected output.

Comment: The question explicitly specifies Redshift, so I swapped the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No LAG, but a simple MAX over a CASE:

```
max(case when is_unavailable = 1 then date end) -- previous unavailable date
over (partition by product_id
      order by date
      rows unbounded preceding)
```

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth. I tried your query :
select product_id, max(case when unavailable_flag = 1 then date end)
over (partition by product_id) as days_sice_last_unavailable, date from mytable ; but the days_sice_last_unavailable is coming out to be empty.

Comment: @AnkitTripathi: empty? That's impossible unless there flag is never set to 1. I'll modify my answer to match your new description.

Comment: Hi Dnoeth, I was limiting the rows which did not show me the complete picture. Here is the complete query using your solution:

select product_id, date ,is_unavailable,
        DATEDIFF(d,
                max(case when is_unavailable = 1 then date end) -- previous unavailable date
over (partition by product_id
      order by date
      rows unbounded preceding),
                date) as days_sice_last_unavailable 

    FROM #tmp

Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    create table #tmp (product_id INT,[date] DATETIME ,is_unavailable BIT)

    INSERT INTO #tmp
    SELECT 1,'2018-01-01',1
    union
    SELECT 1,'2018-01-02',0
    union
    SELECT 1,'2018-01-03',0
    union
    SELECT 1,'2018-01-04',1


    select product_id, date ,is_unavailable,
        DATEDIFF(d,
                CASE WHEN is_unavailable = 1 THEN date
                ELSE
                    MIN(case when is_unavailable = 1 then date end) over (partition by product_id) END,
                date) as days_sice_last_unavailable 

    FROM #tmp

    drop table #tmp
```

Comment: Thanks Sahi. However, the query keeps calculating days diff from the first broken date rather than last.  For the following data:
INSERT INTO tmp
    SELECT 1,'2018-01-01',1
    union
    SELECT 1,'2018-01-02',0
    union
    SELECT 1,'2018-01-03',0
    union
    SELECT 1,'2018-01-04',1
    union
    select 1,'2018-01-05',0
    union
    select 1,'2018-01-06',0

The output is:
0,1,2,0,4,5 instead of 0,1,2,0,1,2